# Install4j: Unix Installer causes bin/unpack200: not found

Tags: linux, 64-bit, install4j

we use a setup, created with install4j (we still use 5.0.11). On a new local unix machine (Linux version 3.8.13-44.1.4.el6uek.x86_64) this setup failed, the log shows:

```
Unpacking JRE ...
micsetup.sh: 210: micsetup.sh: bin/unpack200: not found
Preparing JRE ...
Error unpacking jar files. The architecture or bitness (32/64) of the bundled JVM might not match your machine.
```

Searching for this error I found this:

> the program tries to run the file /bin/unpack200 which does not exist. However, the file /usr/bin/unpack200 does exist. This is due to the fact that this file is in different places depending on the architecture of the machine used - if it is 32bits, it is in one place, if it is 64bits, it is in the other. I am having this problem because the file was made to run on a 32bit architecture but I am using a 64bits machine. Therefore to fix this problem one must install 32bits libraries.

After running

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

our setup works.

My question: is there a way to configure the "Unix installer" in install4j to build the setup, that it works on 64 bit Linux systems like the mentioned without installing additional libraries on this system? I think not all of our customers would allow this.

Thanks in advance!

Frank

Comment: Why don't you try to modify micsetup.sh in order to detect the architecture by yourself and use the right path? Which JRE do you package? I don't remember having this kind of problem with OpenJDK and using it is less constraining as it isn't under the Oracle Binary Code License.

Comment: To modify the shell script created by install4j is no option. 

We decided to follow Ingo's answer and created separate unix media files including either 32bit or 64bit JRE.

Comment: Ingo's suggestion is easier to implement, it's the way to go if providing several packages doesn't bother you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such functionality in install4j. Bundling JREs on Linux is generally problematic.

One strategy would be to offer installers with 32-bit JRE and installers with 64-bit JREs.

Comment: Bundling JREs on Linux isn't generally problematic, it's perfectly doable. Don't make any confusion between Linux limitations and install4j limitations. The launch script just has to call the JRE bundled with the application, it's the same under Mac OS X and Windows. This is what I do and it works. install4j doesn't support multi-architecture packages as far as I know and anyway, it's better to provide a separate package per architecture as you suggest, especially if you use some native libraries.

Comment: @guuessej You're right that install4j does not support JRE bundles for multiple architectures. However, the Oracle JRE has problems on some Linux distributions with respect to AWT functionality while the OpenJDK build compiled for the distribution does not. Also, it's not possible to determine in general from a shell script if a 32-bit JRE will work or not.

Comment: Actually, it depends on which problems you're talking about. The fullscreen mode in AWT is broken both in Oracle Java and in OpenJDK (I failed to port some working NEWT code to AWT), they share more than 97% of the source code, there are only minor differences in fonts, sound and codecs. You can use "less /proc/cpuinfo" or "lscpu" to get the architecture under Linux. If you want to use a cross-platform API, look at libcpuid. There is a better solution that will be supported in LWJGL 3 but I have forgotten its name :s

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a matter of finding out the CPU architecture. Sometimes 32-bit library installations are incomplete in some 64-bit Linux distributions and there's no good way to detect that from a shell script.